# MS Teams, Dark Mode, Task with Adaptive card - wrong colors (Microsoft Teams Version 1.4.00.26376 (64-bit). It was last updated on 10/5/2021.)

Tags: microsoft-teams

Ver: Microsoft Teams Version 1.4.00.26376 (64-bit). It was last updated on 10/5/2021

Dark Mode. Task - AdaptiveCard (v 1.3).
[image]

Wrong background ...

Default mode:

[image]

Objects: Input.Text & TextBlock

{

"$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",

"type": "AdaptiveCard",

"version": "1.3",

"body": [

```
{

  "type": "ColumnSet",

  "columns": [

    {

      "type": "Column",

      "width": "auto",

      "items": [

        {

          "type": "TextBlock",

          "text": "Text",

          "color": "Accent",

          "weight": "Bolder"

        }

      ]

    },

    {

      "type": "Column",

      "width": "auto",

      "items": [

        {

          "type": "TextBlock",

          "text": "${Text}",

          "wrap": true,

          "color": "Accent",

          "weight": "Bolder"

        }

      ]

    }

  ]

},

{

  "type": "Input.Text",

  "id": "Emails",

  "value": "${Emails}",

  "isMultiline": true,

  "placeholder": "Enter emails ... "

}
```

],

"actions": [

```
{

  "type": "Action.Submit",

  "title": "Cancel"

},

{

  "type": "Action.Submit",

  "title": "Add",

  "id": "Add",

  "data": {

    "Type": "Add",

    "Action": "Add",

    "Id": "${Id}"

  }

}
```

]

}

Comment: And what's your question? If you are facing a bug with Teams, why not report it to Microsoft?

Comment: We are able to repro this issue. We have raised a bug and the concerned team is looking into it. Thanks!